# Asymptotic analysis - order functions

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

Can you please help to answer the following question:

> Arrange the following functions in increasing order of growth rate
>   (with `g(n)` following `f(n)` in your list if and only if
>   `f(n)=O(g(n))`).
>
> 1. `sqr(n)`
> 2. `10^n`
> 3. `n^1.5`
> 4. `2^sqr(log(n))`
> 5. `n^5/3`

I used logarithmic approach for each option - my answer is 13542. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about CS theory and does not relate to programming.  It might be better suited to Math.SE or MathOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer looks correct. Taking the logs of all of these gives

1. .5
2. n lg 10
3. 1.5
4. √(log n)
5. 1.6

This would be ordered 1, 3, 5, 4, 2.

Hope this helps!